Ignore empty cell in case of condition
I have :
id= c("2019-08-01", "2019-08-06", "2019-08-10") 
bid = c("2", "4", "7") 
ask = c("3", NA, "8")
df1 = data.frame(id, bid, ask)

I have to impose the condition of ask>bid, and not eliminate the lines with NA (where only one of the ask or bid is NA).
I tried multiple methods, nothing worked.
The main idea is to specify:
df1<-df1[ask>bid]

I just do not know how to mention to leave the row alone/ignore it if either ask or bid is NA (not both).
Thank you.
I tried multiple methods, nothing worked.
